# How to test a non-organic install Appsflyer on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, appsflyer

I really add my device on white list to test and then I follow step bellow:
https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207032066-AppsFlyer-SDK-Integration-iOS#integration
On the device, I clicked on the URL and the Safari redirected to the app store.
I install my app on Xcode but the log is organic install, I don't know why it's always organic install

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: No, not yet. Have you any idea to solve it?

Comment: Did you open link through the any device application (e.g. Notes)? Install will not be tracked  as non-organic if you open appsflyer link directly from Safari browser

Comment: Also you should correctly setup appsflyer campaign on the appsflyer side. I hadn't received non-organic install till UA specialist reconfigured appsflyer campaign.

Answer (score 0):

My checklist:

1. Double check implementation (check that 'URL types' in the info.plist file and 'Associated domains' in Signing & Capabilities tab are setup correctly with no typos)
2. Check that device is whitelisted on the appsflyer side
3. Generate  deeplink on the appsflyer side (since I have no access to appsflyer side I don't know what parameters should be added to link, but in my case link should have 'media source' and 'campaign' params)
4. Remove installed app from device, send url to the device and open it (I always copy-paste link to the Notes app - direct copy-paste to the Safari doesn't work). You should be redirected to the Appstore app page from Safari. Leave device on that page and install app from xCode
5. Check `conversionInfo["af_status"]` value on `onConversionDataSuccess` method

If deeplinking works well but you can't get non-organic install issue might be on the 3rd step. Try to reconfigure appsflyer link and try one more time

You can also check [this flow](https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/appsflyer-flutter-plugin/issues/25#issuecomment-605814839). It's almost same except 3rd step:

> Replace the following parameters:
> app_id - ID of the app that is being tested
> pid - media source name (for example “SDKTest”)
> c - campaign name
> IDFA/advertising_id - Advertising ID if the device used for the test

**UPD (GDPR related)**

If you call `AppsFlyerLib.shared.anonymizeUser = true` before you call `AppsFlyerLib.shared.start()` you will always get organic install

Answer (score 0):

Many years later. I continue to work with AppsFlyer SDK. I asked for technical support from the help center of AppsFlyer and
they said: "**They could see the UDL was called in the log, but it didn't get the parameter since the IP addresses when clicking the link and opening the app were different. Kindly try to use the same network by clicking and installing.**”

Finally, I used the same network for my Mac and iPhone and I can test it ok

Note: You'll need to upgrade the plan first before testing with the mobile app.